# ElasticSearch Regular Expression

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

Trying to apply a regular expression to the below using ElasticSearch 1.1.1:

```
127.0.0.1:35946 [27/Jul/2014:15:18:54.097] api.ch.gov.uk-d9928e1_18001 api.xx.yy.zz-d9928e1_18001/api.xx.yy.zz-d9928e1-1 0/0/0/65/15066 200 1956 - - ---- 2/1/1/0/0 0/0 "GET /company/12345678 HTTP/1.1"
```

Starting with `"127.0.0.1"` is fine, but adding anything else to the regexp stops it matching, even adding `.+`. I thought `"127.0.0.1".+?GET /company/\d+` would work.

What am I missing?

Comment: what do you want to match exactly?

Comment: Not a generic regexp question, but specifically ES regexp. I really want to know why, in ES, `START` but not `START.+` match against `START MORE`. According to the docs, that won't work. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, hope someone has had a similar problem.

Comment: sorry, never heard about elastic search before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

> Lucene’s patterns are always anchored. The pattern provided must match
>   the entire string.

So your pattern will only match if you match it fully like you do with `^` and `$` anchors

Use this regex if you want to match :

```
127.0.0.1.+?GET \/company\/\d+\s+\w+\/\d+\.\d+\"
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's not happening that way. 
What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just try the below regex to match from `127.0.0.1` to `/company/12345678`,

```
127\.0\.0\.1.+?GET \/company\/\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tH6eS3/2)

To match the whole string,

```
127\.0\.0\.1.+?GET \/company\/\d+.*
```